# How to reply to particular tweet using Twitter API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

I know this is duplicate question but, Twitter has changed its API.

I can search for a particular keyword, and I can favorite statuses, but I am not able to reply to them. I am using Ruby.

I just want to reply to a particular tweet. I've tried the code below but it is not working.

```
client.update('@nikujii work', in_reply_to_status_id : 569186681850601472)
```

This is the original code:

```
require 'twitter'
    #load 'twitter_config.rb'
    #Create seprate config file.
    #Encrprty ur keys using md5.

    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = "11111111111"
      config.consumer_secret = "333333333333333333"
      config.access_token = "111111111111111"
      config.access_token_secret = "22222222222222"
    end

    #add authentication for different users.
    print "please Enter the key word or phares you want to search?"
    keyword_value= gets.chomp;
    keyword_value.gsub!(' ','%20')
    key_words="\"#{keyword_value}\""
    print key_words;
    print "Number of followers you want to follow(Please enter number from 1 to 100)"
    count_number = gets.chomp;
    count=1;
    #validate user inputs, using reg exp.

    client.search(key_words, result_type: "recent").take(Integer(count_number)).collect do |tweet|
      puts "Count       Tweet URl                 Username                                    tweet"           
      puts "(#{count} #{tweet.url})    #{tweet.user.screen_name}                          #{tweet.text}";
      sleep(3);
      count=count+1;

      client.follow("#{tweet.user.screen_name}");
      #client.favorite.create("#{tweet.user.screen_name}")
      #client.favorites("#{tweet.url}");
      client.fav tweet;  
      client.update('@nikujii work', in_reply_to_status_id : 569186681850601472)

    #client.favorites("#{tweet.id}","#{tweet.user.screen_name}",https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json)
    end
```

Comment: Why doesn't the code work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: not, i think when you want to reply tweet you need some authorized user to approve your app.. with out reply tweet will not work .. @MikeSlutsky

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is in the update line.
Change this:

```
client.update('@nikujii work', in_reply_to_status_id : 569186681850601472)
```

to this:

```
client.update('@nikujii work', in_reply_to_status_id: 569186681850601472)
```

Notice the colon. in your code it has a space between the in_reply_to_status_id to the colon.